# Bi-directional replication for the same MySQL table

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqladmin

AppA stores/retrieves data from dbA.tableA
AppB stores/retrieves data from dbB.tableA

tableA definition is the same across these databases. To start with dbB.tableA was copied from dbA.tableA (assuming both had 5 rows).

row6 was created by AppA (say primary key 6)
row7 was created by AppB (say primary key 7)

I would like row7 to be copied to dbA.tableA and row6 to dbB.tableA

1. Is this even possible to setup bi-directional replication, so that the AppA, AppB view the same data at any point in time.
2. If the primary key is an auto-increment, would it be possible to maintain integrity of data or is there a possibility that there would be collisions on the primary key.

Comment: Are both dbA and dbB in the same physical server?

Comment: Can you check if Multi master replication would work? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

Comment: @altmannmarcelo dbA and dbB are in different machines. dbA is in RDS and dbB is a non RDS instance

Comment: @Rpj Are both MySQL ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming these are different instances of MySQL (most likely on different servers).

You can set up Master-master replication, where dbA is a master of dbB and vice versa.

Then, to avoid auto-increment collisions, set the following in `my.cnf` on dbA:

```
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=1
```

And the following on dbB:

```
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=2
```

Comment: @rpj Please note that the increment config will not solve collisions in the case of a deletes/updates, and it can lead to replication breaking and/or having inconsistent data.

Comment: @jynus Do you mean deletes/updates on primary key only?

Comment: No, simultaneous deletes and updates on the same rows (no matter the field) will break replication as there is no procedure for conflict resolution/rollbacking. Check these slides (specially page 10 and 11): http://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2013/sites/default/files/slides/Hazards%20of%20Multi-writing.pdf